# How to get feature information from a WFS at a certain coordinate (in Python)?

Tags: qgis, python, wfs, owslib

I have a WebFeatureService at a remote url. It contains different 'layers'/ types.

How do I get information at a certain point (lat, lng) similar to what QGIS returns when you click the map using the 'Identify Features' option (see screenshot)?

[image: QGIS Identify Features]

The `getfeature` method of `owslib` only lets me input bounding boxes (bbox) and not a coordinate. Is there a simple way to get this information?

Comment: You already have the features so just try a contains on each one's geometry in the client

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton. Do you have some sample Python code? What lib to use? I use owslib to connect to the WFS source.